# Лишный фрейм <iframe> в Google chrome и opera при работе на локальном сервере

Tags: javascript, html5

В HTML создал таймер обратного отсчета. Всё работает нормально, но на странице под таймером появляется фрейм. В Google chrome нажимаю F12 и вижу лишний тег фрейма:

```html
<iframe src="//rotorengine.ru/res/if.html?r=0.164740544045344" name="dpmsi"></iframe>
```

Включил  ADBlockerPlus, но ничего не изменяется. В чем причина и где выход?

см. рисунок developer tool:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой HTML код:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html >
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="timer.js"></script>

    <title>timer </title>
    <meta  charset=utf-8" />

 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="timer_wrap">

       <div id="clock">

            <div id="day">
                 <p id="day0"></p>
                 <p id="day1"></p>
                 <p id="day2"></p>
            </div>

            <div id="sep">
            :
            </div>

            <div id="hour">
                 <p id="hour0"></p>
                 <p id="hour1"></p>
            </div>

            <div id="sep">
            :
            </div>

             <div id="min">
                  <p id="min0"></p>
                  <p id="min1"></p>
             </div>

            <div id="sep">
            :
            </div>

            <div id="sec">
                  <p id="sec0"></p>
                  <p id="sec1"></p>
            </div>

       </div>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Или этот тег скрипта откуда оказалась тоже интересно? (хотя в отличие от первого ничего не мешает - пока!):

```html
<script async="" src="//js.textshift.net/lib.js?tempname=e80d279a4cf6cc53a0fd4d86576012a5022cc2a7"></script>
```

Версии Google Chrome, Opera, Firefox последние, но в Firefox фрейм не вижу, только в Google и Opera.

Answer (score 1):

отключайте расширения браузера по очереди. Какое-то из них генерирует вредоносный скрипт. У меня это был Gmarkt

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Это называется личный опыт. Если нужны подробности, то я их описывал здесь http://blog.themarfa.name/permalink/7bcd8c5ed1 . Сейчас скажите, что нельзя ссылку указывать?